# What does "Motions along translation axes induce the opposite orientations on the region they bound" mean?

Tags: matrices, hyperbolic-geometry

I am reading a paper and they mention the following: "Two isometries of the hyperbolic plane are said to be co-parallel if they have disjoint axes and the motions along these axes induce the opposite orientations on the region they bound"

I am very confused by what is meant by that (visually w.r.t to the fixed points) in the upper-half plane. Consider two hyperbolic matrices $A,B$ and assume they have disjoint axis. Denote $a^+,a^-$ ($b^+,b^-$) as attracting/repelling fixed points of $A$ (of $B$) respectively. In my head, what the above means is that either $b^+>b^-$ and $a^+>a^-$ or $b^+<b^-$ and $a^+<a^-$. Visually, the translation axis "point" in the same direction when pointing towards the attracting point. However, doing some computations using the results in the paper, my understanding is wrong. Could anyone explain what is meant by the above?

For example:
$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1.01179 & -2.92967 \\
 2.38967 & 5.93101 \\
\end{array}
\right),B=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -0.244863 & 2.47968 \\
 -0.635634 & 2.35302 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Are co-parallel, but $a^+=-0.51231,a^-= -2.39302$ and $b^+=1.5192,b^-= 2.56787$

Thank you!

Comment: Each nontrivial translation $T$ along a geodesic induces orientation on this geodesic (so that $T$ moves points in the positive direction). If you have a planar domain $D$ whose boundary contains an oriented arc $A$, then $D$ has unique orientation consistent  with the orientation of $A$. Can you figure out the rest on your own?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I thought that is what my description was saying. On the translation axis of $A$, points move towards $a^+$ inducing and orientation. Similarly, with $B$ points move towards $b^+$. So the orientation is the same if the inequalities I wrote in the post hold. Could you point out the error?

Comment: I do not understand your computations. But there might be some errors in the paper you are reading. Your interpretation using inequalities is correct but I do not like the fact that it depends on a particular model of the hyperbolic plane and also that it excludes vertical geodesics.

Comment: @MoisheKohan So I am correct, that if using the cited definition,  two matrices are co-parallel $\iff$ the attracting fixed points are either both larger than their respective repelling fixed point, or both smaller than their respective repelling fixed point. In the paper the give a condition to check if two matrices are co-parallel, according to that they are, but the fixed points indicate otherwise.

Comment: Actually, your interpretation is correct for some configurations but not for other configurations. If your axes bound disjoint half-disks, then your interpretation is wrong.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Okay, that means the paper has no error hopefully :). Could you explain why my interpretation is not correct for other configurations? I would be grateful. Do you mean on other models of the Hyperbolic plane?

Comment: No, I mean the upper half-plane model. Just draw a picture of a configuration in my comment and you will see what is wrong.

Comment: If the half-disks are disjoint (You mean one geodesic doesn't encompass the other, correct?) then according to my inequalities the translation axis "point" in the same direction and so they have the same orientation. If the half-disks are not disjoint then again, the translation axis point in the same diection so the orientation is the same.Why would it matter whether the half circles are disjoint or not?

Comment: You are wrong about nested disks. Draw a picture again. In your OP you correctly described the case of nested disks and now, for some reason, you are making a mistake.

Comment: @MoisheKohan for the past hour i have been drawing pictures lol. if they are nested then for instance the ordering is $b^-<a^-<a^+<b^+$ so my inequalities hold. The orientation is $b^-->b^+$ and $a^-->a^+$. I am starting to feel like I have some fundamental misunderstanding of the picture here.

Comment: Maybe I will write an answer then, it just will take me some time to add pictures: without these, it is hard to explain what is going on. One thing you should remember: if you have two oriented arcs on the boundary of a domain then they induce the same orientation of the domain iff the following holds: As you travel along the arcs, the domain should be to the same side from you (say, left side for both arcs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you have two oriented arcs on the boundary of a domain $D$ in the plane. Then the two arcs define the same orientation on if and only if, as you travel along these arcs in the direction of their orientation, the domain is to the same side from you. (I can add a formal definition if you wish.) Now, consider two examples. In the first example the two arcs define the same orientation on $D$: As you travel along the both arcs, the domain is to the left from you.

[image]

In the second example, the arcs define opposite orientations on $D$: As you travel along the red arc, the domain is to the left from you, while as you travel along the blue arc, the domain is to the right from you.

[image]

Note that in both cases, the inequalities $a_-< a_+, b_-< b_+$ are satisfied. Hence, your conjecture about orientation in terms of stated inequalities between $a_\pm, b_\pm$ is (in general) false. This probably explains why you are getting answers different from the ones in the paper you are reading.

More precisely, your conjecture fails if the geodesic arcs bound disjoint half-disks in the upper half-plane. The conjecture holds if the arcs bound nested half-disks.

Comment: Thank you! What I was confused is the second picture. I assumed D was outside the blue region, not in-between red and blue.